# D-Link DIR-655 Router rebooting itself randomly

Tags: wireless-networking, router, reboot

My router keeps restarting itself randomly, usually when skype call is in progress, which is the worst time for reboot to me.

The leds blinks and all wireless clients are dropped during restart. Also the internet connection blinks orange during that time.

I'm connected through N standart @300 mbits, so the wifi settings are the best i could achieve.
I've tried changing various settings, updated to the latest firmware, etc, but it starts rebooting few weeks ago suddenly. Before, it was working OK for few months.

Do you know what the reason could be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've also found that my router is not overheating.

After several days of googling and trying I've found the solution. There are two things, which may create problems.

1. If you're seeing message "Router is currently measuring internet speed" or something like that when you connect to the router, you can use this solution:

   - go to Advanced / QOS engine
   - make sure Automatic uplink speed is NOT checked.
   - you can manually setup your internet speeds, so your router will not periodically check the speed
   - or you can turn OFF the whole Traffic shaping
2. If this didn't help, there is one more thing. The router periodically checks for occupied wireless channels and tries to find the unoccupied one, and then - restarts the wireless part to change the channel. To deny this behaviour:

   - setup / wireless settings / manual wireless settings (button)
   - uncheck Enable Auto Channel Scan
   - use some utility on your mobile or pc to find unnocupied channels. I use "WifiExplorer" on my android.
   - set the channel to the free channel. Remember, channel numbers are not any magical number, it's just slightly changing used frequency.

Comment: After several days with solution above, which was better than before, but it was still kind of unstable, so I decided to return it to the shop. :(

Answer (score 0):

These routers are known for being clocked too high which causes overheating, they need a heatsink mounted on the CPU, this will solve the restarting issues.

Comment: Do you have a source for this claim?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same router and problem. In my case, it was wife's Samsung S4 that was taking down the network. Several other devices connected without issue including my cell phone, but for some reason her phone crashed the network when she connected to the Wi-Fi network. We tried many things which did not work, and in our case the solution was to create a Guest Zone on the router to which she connected with her Samsung S4.

Answer (score -1):

I also had a randomly rebooting DIR-655.  My solution was to disable WPA2 and only allow WPA as wireless security setting.  That setting stopped the random reboots.

Comment: Generally not a good idea, WPA is insecure and shouldn't really be used

Answer (score -2):

If the ISP modem has a built in router, it's best to bridge the modem. Having 2 routers on the same line can cause connection problems: Link>http://www.practicallynetworked.com/networking/fixing_double_nat.htm and http://computer.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm If the modem can't be bridged then see if the modem has a DMZ option and input the IP address the router gets from the modem and put that into the modems DMZ. Also check the routers DHCP IP address maybe conflicting with the ISP modems IP address of 192.168.0.1. Check to see if this is the same on the ISP modem, and if modem can't be bridged, change the DIR router to 192.168.1.1 or .0.254.

QoS will work fine if there isn't any NAT before the DIR-655 router.

Comment: Actually, that wasn't my problem.